# Power shell command to get installed software and sort by pc name

Tags: sorting, powershell, scripting

I am trying to let the script below:

- Get all the installed software on a number of computers and Sort by computer name, and not list all the software all together.

This is my code -

```
param(

[string[]]$computername='testpc'

)

Get-WmiObject -computername $computername -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, description, installdate, vendor | Sort-Object Name > C:\desktop-apps.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the PSComputerName property to your Select-Object and Sort-Object calls:

```
Get-WmiObject -computername $computername -Class Win32_Product |
Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, Name, description, installdate, vendor  |
Sort-Object PSComputerName, Name
```